# I'm unable to to add "count(Result) as GamesPlayed" to anywhere in this MS SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server

HERE is My Query. I want add count(Result) as GamesPlayed in this MS SQL Query. But it shows error when i try to do that. Please help me out.

```
SELECT DENSE_RANK() OVER (
        ORDER BY Point DESC
            ,GD DESC
        ) AS Rank
    ,*
FROM (
    SELECT TName
        ,Sum(Score) AS Score
        ,Sum(GA) AS GA
        ,Sum(Diff) AS GD
        ,Sum(Point) AS Point
    FROM (
        SELECT f.teamID
            ,Score AS Score
            ,GA AS GA
            ,Score - GA AS DIff
            ,CASE 
                WHEN Result = 'W'
                    THEN 3
                WHEN Result = 'D'
                    THEN 1
                ELSE 0
                END AS Point
            ,T.TName
        FROM Fixtures F
        INNER JOIN Teams T ON t.TeamID = f.TeamID
        ) S
    GROUP BY teamID
        ,TName
    ) SS
ORDER BY Point DESC
    ,GD DESC
```

Comment: We can help but you have to help us. You say you got an error message? What is the error? What is the query you tried? What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: This is the query i tried get the result i want: 
 'Select DENSE_RANK() OVER(order by Point DESC,GD DESC) as Rank, * from (select  TName,Sum(Score) as Score,Sum(GA) as GA,Sum(Diff) as GD,Sum(Point) as Point from  (Select f.teamID,Score as Score,GA as GA,Score-GA as DIff,
case 
when Result = 'W' then 3
when Result = 'D' then 1
Else 0
end as Point,T.TName, Count(Result) as GamesPlayed
from Fixtures F
inner join  Teams T on t.TeamID = f.TeamID  ) S
group by teamID,TName) SS
order by Point DESC,GD DESC'

Comment: This is the ERROR i get when i try this query: 
Column 'Fixtures.TeamID' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause

Comment: This is actually soccer league table and i'm trying to get number of games played by teams as Games Played column. I hope you are clear now :)

Comment: AND by the way everything else works perfectly fine without adding that part into query. ( count(Result) as GamesPlayed ).

Comment: Where exactly do you want to add this count?

Comment: I want to show it to the final result. So adding it to first part of query would do that normally. But its not possible that way. So i'm stuck now!

Comment: Check if a group aggregate like `count(Result) over (partition by TName)` returns th expected result.

Comment: ERROR When i did that. "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'over' " It doesn't make any sense :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT DENSE_RANK() OVER (
        ORDER BY Point DESC
            ,GD DESC
        ) AS Rank
    ,*
FROM (
    SELECT TName
        ,Sum(Score) AS Score
        ,Sum(GA) AS GA
        ,Sum(Diff) AS GD
        ,Sum(Point) AS Point
        ,COUNT(result) AS GamesPlayed  -- Get games played
    FROM (
        SELECT f.teamID
            ,Score AS Score
            ,GA AS GA
            ,Score - GA AS DIff
            ,CASE 
                WHEN Result = 'W'
                    THEN 3
                WHEN Result = 'D'
                    THEN 1
                ELSE 0
                END AS Point
            , result  --Had to add result to this derived table to be used outside
            ,T.TName
        FROM Fixtures F
        INNER JOIN Teams T ON t.TeamID = f.TeamID
        ) S
    GROUP BY teamID
        ,TName
    ) SS
ORDER BY Point DESC
    ,GD DESC
```